# Creating SQL Server vulnerability assessment resource using a private Storage Account fails

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL Server resource for which I try to create a `azurerm_mssql_server_vulnerability_assessment` using Terraform. For this I am using a private storage account (no public access / private endpoints). My code for this is the following:

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server_security_alert_policy" "mssql_security_alert_policy" {
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  server_name         = azurerm_mssql_server.this.name
  state               = "Enabled"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server_vulnerability_assessment" "mssql_vulnerability_assessment" {
  server_security_alert_policy_id = azurerm_mssql_server_security_alert_policy.mssql_security_alert_policy.id
  storage_container_path          = "${azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.primary_blob_endpoint}${azurerm_storage_container.sql_defender_storage_account_container.name}/"
  storage_account_access_key      = azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.primary_access_key

  recurring_scans {
    enabled = true
  }
}

# Allow the database to act as a contributor to the storage account for vulnerability assessments
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sql_blob_container_contributor" {
  principal_id = azurerm_mssql_server.this.identity[0].principal_id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
  scope        = azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.id
}
```

And for the storage account:

```
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sql_defender_storage_account" {
  name                     = "sqldefender${var.stage}"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  location                 = var.location
  resource_group_name      = var.resource_group_name

  network_rules {
    default_action = var.deny_public_access ? "Deny" : "Allow"
    bypass = [
      "AzureServices", "Logging", "Metrics"
    ]

    private_link_access {
      endpoint_resource_id = azurerm_mssql_server.this.id
    }
    
  }

  tags = module.label_mssql_server.tags
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "mssql_server_defender_storage_account" {
  location            = var.location
  name                = "pe-to-${var.private_endpoint_name}-${azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.name}-blob"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = var.private_endpoints_subnet_id
  tags                = module.label_mssql_server.tags

  private_service_connection {
    is_manual_connection           = false
    //noinspection HILUnresolvedReference
    name                           = "private-serviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.id
    subresource_names              = [
      "blob"
    ]
  }
}

# Create a DNS record for the private storage account
resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "sql_defender_storage_account" {
  provider = azurerm.common

  name    = azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.name
  records = azurerm_private_endpoint.mssql_server_defender_storage_account.custom_dns_configs.0.ip_addresses

  resource_group_name = var.common_resource_group_name
  ttl                 = 300
  zone_name           = var.blob_storage_dns_zone
  tags                = module.label_mssql_server.tags
}

# Create the storage account name
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "sql_defender_storage_account_container" {
  name                  = "sqldefendercontainer"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.name
  container_access_type = "private"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_private_dns_a_record.sql_defender_storage_account ]
}
```

However when attempting to apply the created plan I get the following error:

> Error: updataing mssql server vulnerability assessment:    sql.ServerVulnerabilityAssessmentsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=504 --
>
> Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error.
>
> Status=504 Code="GatewayTimeout" Message="The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Sql' within the specified time period."

I am not really sure why this is happening. I suspect it might have to do with private endpoints but I am not 100% sure. Can anyone potentially shed some light here?

Comment: hello @akortex, may i know if private endpoint is also enabled for sql server? or its only storage account ?

Comment: Private endpoints are enabled for the sql server as well

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT I need to have everything private in order to satisfy ISO compliance rules. However when locking down everything, adding the vulnerability assessment for the database is not feasible. On the contrary, when having a public storage account everything works fine.

Comment: yes , you are correct i tried the same and its provides the same error as you are receiving ,  but when i create the exact same thing it succeeds from portal .., i observed it creates a system-managed-identity for the server and assigns it the role of Storage blob data contributor and thats why it succeeds .. i am testing the same for terraform will let you know.

Comment: Huh, that could make sense. I tried the same thing as you mentioned for the extended auditing policy (which seems to also need a system assigned identity and a role) -- which it did not work. I haven't tried this for the assessment though. I also did not think of checking the ARM template as you did. Let me know if you have any success.

Comment: it was successful will post the same as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned in comments , we require to use a Managed Identity for the SQL Server and then provide the same identity `Storage Blob Data Contributor` for the storage created from terraform.

I enabled System Managed Identity on the existing SQL Server and then provided Storage Blob Data Contributor from terraform code.

[image]

Then I used the below code for the requirement that you have :

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}

#SystemMangedIdentity For the SQL Server
data "azuread_service_principal" "sqlsystemidentity" {
   display_name = "ansuman-sql"
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "myresourcegroup"
}
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name = "ansuman-vnet"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}
data "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name = "storage"
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

data "azurerm_mssql_server" "server" {
  name = "ansuman-sql"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sql_defender_storage_account" {
  name                     = "sqldefenderansuman123"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  network_rules {
    default_action = "Deny"
    ip_rules = ["myclientip"]
    bypass = [
      "AzureServices", "Logging", "Metrics"
    ]
  }
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "sqltoblobcontributor" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
  principal_id         = data.azuread_service_principal.sqlsystemidentity.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "mssql_server_defender_storage_account" {
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  name                = "pe-to-ansumanprivate-${azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.name}-blob"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet.id

  private_service_connection {
    is_manual_connection           = false
    //noinspection HILUnresolvedReference
    name                           = "private-serviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.id
    subresource_names              = [
      "blob"
    ]
  }
}

# private DNS
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "privatelink.blob.core.windows.net"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_private_endpoint.mssql_server_defender_storage_account
  ]
}

#private DNS Link
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "${azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.name}-dnslink"
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
  registration_enabled = false
}

# Create the storage account name
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "sql_defender_storage_account_container" {
  name                  = "sqldefendercontainer"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.name
  container_access_type = "private"
  depends_on = [ azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.example]
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server_security_alert_policy" "mssql_security_alert_policy" {
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  server_name         = data.azurerm_mssql_server.server.name
  state               = "Enabled"
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server_vulnerability_assessment" "mssql_vulnerability_assessment" {
  server_security_alert_policy_id = azurerm_mssql_server_security_alert_policy.mssql_security_alert_policy.id
  storage_container_path          = "${azurerm_storage_account.sql_defender_storage_account.primary_blob_endpoint}${azurerm_storage_container.sql_defender_storage_account_container.name}/"
}
```

**Note:**

I removed Storage access key parameter from vulnerability assessment block as it will be optional and not required while using identities.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have followed your recommendation and unfortunately I am still unable to get it working. I have also enabled the system managed identity as you did and moreover I have also set a private access link network rule for the storage account. However I am still getting the same 504 error, when attempting to apply the configuration.

Comment: I also see that you did not provide a `storage_access_key` for the vulnerability assessment resource. Is this not needed?

Comment: Hello @akortex yes it's not needed as I have mentioned in the answer while using managed identity we don't require access key . As the access will be provide to identity as rbac role i.e. storage blob data contributor.