# The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Sql' within the specified time period

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines

I am running terraform via Azure devOps pipeline, in order to create azure MSSQL along with Blob Auditing Policies. However, when I run the pipeline, I am getting the following error after the pipeline runs for a while. Can some please help me identifying the root cause of this issue?

Error: failure in issuing create/update request for SQL Database "Identity" Blob Auditing Policies(SQL Server ""/ Resource Group ""): sql.ExtendedDatabaseBlobAuditingPoliciesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=504 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=504 Code="GatewayTimeout" Message="The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Sql' within the specified time period."

on azure-sql-server.tf line 92, in resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "sqlserver":
92: resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "sqlserver" {

Comment: Please check it is related to same error, it may help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/105072/export-database-fails-with-34the-gateway-did-not-r.html

Answer (score 1):

> **failure in issuing create/update request for SQL Database "Identity" Blob Auditing Policies(SQL Server ""/ Resource Group ""): sql.ExtendedDatabaseBlobAuditingPoliciesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=504 -- Original Error:
> autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=504
> Code="GatewayTimeout" Message="The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Sql' within the specified time period.**

**To resolve the above error, please try the following:**

- Try removing the `azurerm_mssql_database_extended_auditing_policy`  try replacing with the old **`extended_auditing_policy`** block within **`azurerm_mssql_database`** .
- Using storage requires to enable ***'Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account'*** on the storage account.
- Make sure you have **`Storage Blob Data Contributor`** for the storage created from terraform.
- Enable ***System Managed Identity*** on the existing SQL Server.
- For the workaround, try editing the state file to remove the *"status": "tainted"*, line from the "**`azurerm_mssql_server`**" resource.

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

[azure - Creating SQL Server vulnerability assessment resource using a private Storage Account fails - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69798921/creating-sql-server-vulnerability-assessment-resource-using-a-private-storage-ac?msclkid=32ca9c6fbf2911eca6d373a32f23cb7b).

[mssql_server: breaking change in the azure api · Issue #8915 · hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm · GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8915#issuecomment-712797383).

[Export database fails with "The gateway did not receive a response from 'Microsoft.Sql'" - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/105072/export-database-fails-with-34the-gateway-did-not-r.html).

Comment: The old extended_auditing_policy is not supported in the newer terraform version. Is there a way that I can make terraform to ignore the resource changes using lifecycle, instead of just the attributes in the resources?

Comment: Your second link to Github (Issue #8915) seems to be unrelated to the error here.